# Did you remind the name of a commercial cd-burner software for Linux?

Tags: burning

A silly question, but culture is made even of silly questions...
A lot of years ago, when I start with Linux(2000-2002) I was the
classical windows user so I was not skilled with cli commands li
ke cdrecord, mkisofs, etc..I remind a software house release one
of the first programs with gui for burning cd's under Linux.
Was commercial, not open source, and it did not had success( who
was so crazy to buy a commercial app when similar apps with gui
but OS and free already exist?).
The question is: someone remind the name of this program?
Is not Nero4Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found!
It was "Fireburner" from "IgD Software" one the few shareware programs released in the first Linux decade(1992-2002). Now the site is closed and the program is abandonware.

The welcome window

[image: The welcome window]

The cd icon as I remind

[image: the cd icon as I remind]

No adapter found

[image: no cd-recorder found]